# Best way to arrange a hairdresser database based on their skills

Tags: database-design, sqlite

I need some help in a smart way to organize a database for a hairdresser shop.

So far, I understand that I need a table for the hairdressers containing usual data such as id, name, etc.

I also think I need a table for the procedures the hairdressers can perform. This table would contain the procedure id, description, time required, cost, price and so on.

But I don't see a good way to link those two tables. For example: Professional A can do procedures #1 and #3, but not #2.

How to include this info in the database?

I thought of two possible ways:

1. Make the procedures be columns in the Professionals table, and assign true in the column in case a professional can perform that procedure;
2. Make the professionals be columns in the Procedures table, assigning true if the procedure can be performed by that professional.
   Either possibilities don't see quite the best way to achieve what I want, specially if the number of professionals/procedures get large.

Since I have very little experience in this, I count on your help giving me some insights in this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is called "many-to-many relationship" (a professional can perform many procedures, and a procedure can be performed by many professionals), it is usually implemented using a "link" or "junction" table. Knowing these terms you will be able to find details.

Comment: Thanks. You must have noted that I'm an amateur. Knowing what to search for is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a junction table that uses the ID from the professionals table and the ID from the procedure table. That way it solves your issue of Professional A only being linked to procedures 1 and 3.

For example:

[image]

Comment: That is not a "fact" table though.